# .Net Core - NSwag multipart/form-data required fields

Tags: .net-core, multipartform-data, nswag

I'm using the [FromForm] annotation to bind a multipart/form-data model.
But when swagger generates swagger.json it skips the required fields.

This causes it to misgenerate the interface in the typescript, putting optional properties that should be required.

Anyone helps?

Class:

```
 [Required]
 public string Name { get; set; }
 
 [Required]
 public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
 
 [Required]
 public DateTime DateOfFundation { get; set; }
```

Swagger.json:

```
    "content": {
                "multipart/form-data": {
                  "schema": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "Name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                      },
                      "Abbreviation": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                      },
                      "DateOfFundation": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "date-time"
                      }
...
```